# Displaying part of text in RichText in bold font

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

How do you make some parts of [spark.components.RichText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RichText.html) bold?

In my Flash / ActionScript 3 programm I have been just using **htmlText** property of a **TextField**, and set it to 1 2 <b>3</b> - but now I'm trying to port my program to Flex 4.5.

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying:

```
myRichtText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow('1 2 3 <s:span fontWeight="bold">4 5</s:span>', TextConverter.TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT);
```

but nothing is displayed. I'd prefer not to use RichEditableText or TextArea.

Comment: So what trouble are you having porting the application to 4.5 ? :)

Comment: I can't figure out, how to display part of RichText in bold font

Comment: So is the `htmlText` gone in Flex 4.5 ? Or using the `<b>` tags doesn't work anymore ? I am sorry but I still haven't used the Flex 4.5 SDK. I don't have it right now to test it.

Comment: My suggestion is to use the s:textarea where u can set the htmlText directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var str:String=rc.text.toString().substr(2,1);
 var str2:String=rc.text.toString().substr(0,2);
         str=str2+"<b>"+str+"</b>";
         rc.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(str, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

Rich Text

```
<s:RichText id="rc" text="123"/>
```

I tried out this way.. In `str` you should have your html text in this case `12<b>3</b>` You can try it by different methods like link provided by Mitul Golakiya..
hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for it...

You should use TextConverter.importToFlow()...

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/06/displaying-html-formatted-text-in-a-spark-richtext-control-in-flex-4/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `RichEditableText`, which has the method `setFormatOfRange()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
myRichtText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow('1 2 3 <b>4 5</b>',  TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```